# MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) keboard and trackpad are not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

As title suggests, keyboard and trackpad are not working. However, force quit (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt/option</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd>) had worked.

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried booting in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) to see if it's because something is loading that is causing the issue?  Hold Shift while booting.  Also, you may want to have your battery looked at as it may be swelling which would could cause the issue

Comment: Yes, I tried. But still those are not working.

Comment: Then it's most likely the top case.(keyboard and trackpad assembly) that is bad and needs to be replaced.  They keyboard and trackpad are USB devices;  plugging in an external one that works indicates there is no problem with that subsystem or with software.   You will either have to take it to be repaired or swap it out yourself unless you have Apple Care.

Answer (score 1):

In this model the trackpad and keyboard plug into the logic board directly, the top case just houses it but has no logical components for those in it.

This issue might not actually be the logic board, if I remember correctly the logic for the keyboard goes to the logic board, route back through the trackpad then back to the logic board via the trackpad IPD cable.

Since you've already reset the SMC and it didn't permanently fix it, I would first try another IPD/trackpad cable, if not resolved then try replacing the trackpad itself next.

It's unlikely to be the keyboard, hopefully not the logic board.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in layman's terms, your computer has crashed because of some application overloading your memory (heap) or got stuck in some sort of infinite loop! That is why nothing works (it's not just your mouse and keyboard, it's everything), but when you press an interrupt key, since it has a higher priority than normal processes, it prevents the CPU to continue the task and pops up the force quit tab. Just figure out what is choking your system via Activity Monitor and kill it.

Comment: Thanks for response Milad. But External keyboard and mouse have been working.